# Extracting an URL from td element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract an URL from a html table. The URL is within an anchor tag inside a td cell. 
The html looks like:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" name="TabName" id="Tab" class="common-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Acme Company</a><br/><span class="f-10">07-11-2016</span></td>
        <td><span>Vendor</span><br>
        <td><a href="http://URL" title="Report Details">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the Python code I have written:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://SourceURL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
# Find table
table = soup.find("table",{"class": "common-table"})
# Find all tr rows
tr = table.find_all("tr")

for each_tr in tr:
    td = each_tr.find_all('td')
    # In each tr rown find each td cell
    for each_td in td:
        print(each_td.text)
        if(each_td.text == "Details"):
```

I traversed all the way to the final td tag that has the URL. How do I extract the URL now?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

`url = each_td.a['href']`